# Dividing array into two parts. Need better solution

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, optimization, partitioning

Given an array of 1's and 0's, divide the array into parts such that the number of 1's in first array is equal to number of 0's in the other. Print the index at which this partition occurs. If there are many such possibilities, find the first of such a partition.

Example code here is given below in python. The answer it prints is 7. It means first array is till `a[7]`. Second array starts from `a[8]` until the end.

This algorithm works fine but I think the complexity is O(n^2). I want a better solution if possible. Any help would be great.

```
def findParts(arr):
    length=len(arr)
    count_ones = 0
    count_zeros = 0
    index=0

    for index in range(length-1):
        if arr[index] == 1:
            count_ones+=1
        for j in range(index+1, length-1):
            if arr[j] == 0:
                count_zeros+=1

    if (count_ones-count_zeros == 0):
        return index
    else:
        count_zeros=0;

a=[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]
print findParts(a)
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation you're using? Because that's not going to work.

Comment: it returns None for me ! and as you have not nested for the order is `O(n)`

Comment: @khelwood: No. :) Formatting in stackoverflow was a problem for me. I just made sure it looked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a linear-time algorithm, and a proof for both the existence of a solution and that that solution is the only possible solution:

```
lst = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

index = 0
leftCount, rightCount = 0, lst.count(0)
while leftCount < rightCount:
    if lst[index] == 1:
        leftCount += 1
    else:
        rightCount -= 1
    index += 1

print(lst[:index], index, lst[index + 1:])
```

This will start at the index 0, leaving the left partition empty, making the count of 1s in the left partition 0. We cound the 0s in the right partition in O(n).

Now, we iteratively move the index, or the divider, to the right. We do that, as long as the leftCount is still lower than the rightCount. If that changes, we have found the solution (as both counts will be equal). As we move to the right, we look at the list element. If it’s a `1`, we add one to the left count; if it’s a `0`, we subtract one from the right count. Ultimately, we will reach the perfect index at which both counts will be equal.

Since we are only changing *one* of the counts in each iteration, there always will be such a solution. And since iterating further would go invalidate the balance again, this is also the proof that there can be only a *single* solution.

As for time complexity, we iterate the list once to count the zeroes, and then we iterate it a second time as we move the boundary. So this is O(n).

Comment: Actually, if you start iterating from the middle rather than from one of the ends (see my answer below), you'll find solution faster in 3/4 of cases (assuming random distribution of the partition site).

Comment: @striving_coder My intention wasn’t to have the most efficient code but to show a clear and simple algorithm for my purpose. I’m sure you can micro-optimize this quite a bit. That being said, I don’t think your solution is actually faster, since you need to splice the list twice. A timeit confirms that on my machine.

Comment: @poke: I would think my counting 2 halves of the list takes exactly the same number of operations as your counting the whole list. If slicing has significant overhead on its own, it can be easily re-written as simple iteration over the array's part.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the divider being positioned at a central element and count total number of 1's in the left part of array ( `#(1)` ) and total number of 0's in the right part ( `#(0)` ).

If `#(1) < #(0)` move the divider one element right and update `#(0)` and `#(1)` accordingly (based on the value of previous divider and the value of new divider).

If `#(1) > #(0)` move the divider one element left and update `#(0)` and `#(1)` accordingly.

You will find the divider in `O(n)`.

You can check for the existence of solution beforehand to prevent infinite looping (in case there's no solution, which is when array has all 0's all 1's).

Here is the code:

```
import math

def findParts(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    index = int(math.ceil(length/2.0))
    count_ones = arr[:index+1].count(1)
    count_zeros = arr[index+1:].count(0)
    if count_ones == 0 or count_ones == length:
        return -1

    while count_ones != count_zeros:
        if count_ones < count_zeros:
            index+=1
            if arr[index] == 1:
                count_ones+=1
            else:
                count_zeros-=1
        else:
            if arr[index] == 1:
                count_ones-=1
            else:
                count_zeros+=1
            index-=1

    return index


a=[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]
print findParts(a)
```

Comment: As the main body is already O(n), and we're working with one's and zeroes, the no solution case can be checked with one other call to count the number of one's in the entire array. If count==len(array) or count == 0 there is no solution